# Cannot connect to dbf file

Tags: vb.net, oledb, foxpro

I'm trying to connect to to a foxpro table (.dbf) from a test vb.net form.
I recieve an OleDbException with the message "Cannot open file c:\emp\emptbl.dbf"

Have tried with both of the following connection strings:

> Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=C:\emp\emptbl.dbf

from the MSDN article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa977092%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

> Provider=vfpoledb;Data Source=C:\emp\emptbl.dbf;Collating Sequence=machine;

from [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/visual-foxpro)

The latter seems to be the type to use when connecting to a single table, but the same exception is thrown regadless of which is used.

I can open and perform the same query okay in visual foxpro 6.0. 
Here's my code:

```
    Dim tbl As DataTable = New DataTable()

        Using con = New OleDbConnection(conString)
            cmd = New OleDbCommand() With {.Connection = con, .CommandType = CommandType.Text}
            Dim sSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM(EMPTBL)"
            cmd.CommandText = sSQL
            Dim adp As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
            con.Open()
            adp.Fill(ds)
            con.Close()
            If (ds.Tables.Count > 0) Then
                tbl = ds.Tables(0)
            End If
        End Using

    Return tbl
```

Comment: Probably is not related, but did you compile for AnyCPU and running on a x64 OS?

Comment: ha HA! Changing to "any cpu" seems to have done something alright. An exception is thrown, but now with the message "The 'vfpoledb' provider is not registered on the local machine". So, that's at least something   to look into now. Thanks!

Comment: No, that means the opposite. You are correctly using the x86 platform and thus you produce 32bit code working with a 32bit drivers regardless of the underlying OS bitness. If you switch to AnyCPU you produce 64bit code on 64bit systems and this code cannot work with 32bit drivers (VFPOLEDB)

Comment: Ah nuts! Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OleDB provider should only connect to the PATH where the tables are... not the actual file name.  Once you connect to the PATH, you can query from ANY .Dbf file that is located in it

Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=C:\emp

select * from emptbl where ...

You can also look at other connection string settings at

[ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/Providers/vfp-ole-db-provider)

UPDATE per comment.

It appears you are getting closer. with your attempt without the () parens.  In VFP, within parens, it interprets that as "look for a variable called EMPTBL", and from its value is the name of the table to query from.  Not something you would need to apply via OleDB connection.

Now, cant open the file is another.  Is it POSSIBLE that another application has the table open and the file is in exclusive use? and thus can not be opened by the .net app too?  Even for grins, if you open VFP, and just do a simple create table in the C:\Emp folder and put a single record in it, then you know no other program will be using it as it is a new file.  Quit out of VFP and try to query THAT table.  There should be no locks, no other program is expecting it, so it should never be opened by anything else and you should be good to go.

Comment: I've had a go with those settings. Getting the message "Variable empTbl" is not found". If I change the query from "SELECT * FROM(EMPTBL)" to "SELECT * FROM EMPTBL" however, I get the previous error  "Cannot open file c:\emp\emptbl.dbf". At this stage its probably just my ignorance of Foxpro coming into play. Thanks

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. Muggins here had the table open in Visual Foxpro. Didn't realise that could be an issue. In either case, I closed out of foxpro, removed the parens in my query, and bingo! Thanks.